# How can I configure dynamically appended Ace Editors without causing extra HTML to be generated as a result?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ace-editor, dynamic-content

Currently, I can dynamically create a new Ace Editor and append it to a container div as so:

```
editorsOnScreen++;
$("#container").append(`<div class="questionContainer w-100" 
                        id="questionContainer_` + editorsOnScreen + `" >
                            <div class="editor" id="editor_` + 
                             editorsOnScreen + `">//Code Here</div>
                        </div>`);
```

I can then configure those Ace Editors individually by referencing their ID using the incrementing variable:

```
var editor = ace.edit("editor_" + editorsOnScreen);
//Perfrom configuration here.
```

If a user leaves the page, I want to be able to save all of the editors on the screen to reshow them next time, so I use `localStorage` to save the `innerHTML` of the `container div` where they are stored:

```
localStorage.setItem("divHtml", $("#container").html();
```

I do this with the intention of then replacing the HTML of the `container div` with the HTML I previously stored the next time the page is loaded.
This is where the problem comes in. I would expect the HTML saved at the key `divHTML` to be the following:

```
<div class="questionContainer w-100" id="questionContainer_` + editorsOnScreen + `" >
    <div class="editor" id="editor_` + editorsOnScreen + `">//Code Here</div>
</div>
```

But, instead, it looks exactly like this (I'm using the three dots because it goes on for lines, and those X's really do come out when I use `console.log`):

```
<div class="questionContainer w-100" id="questionContainer_` + editorsOnScreen + `" >
    <div class="editor ace_editor ace-vibrant-ink ace_dark" id="editor_2"> 
        <textarea class="ace_text-input" wrap="off" autocorrect="off" 
        autocapitalize="off" spellcheck="false" style="opacity: 0;"> 
        </textarea><div class="ace_gutter" aria-hidden="true"><div 
        class="ace_layer ace_gutter-layer ace_folding-enabled"></div><div c 
        class="ace_gutter-active-line"></div></div><div class="ace_scroller" 
        style="left: 0px; right: 0px; bottom: 0px;"><div 
        class="ace_content"><div class="ace_layer ace_print-margin-layer"> 
        <div class="ace_print-margin" style="left: 4px; visibility: hidden;
        ...
        overflow: 
        visible;">XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
        XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
        XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
        XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
        </div></div></div></div>
```

I do however find that I get the exactly the results I expect when I don't include any JavaScript or jQuery to configure the editors.

Why would that happen? How can I go about saving the HTML of the `container div` of which all of the editors are children so that I can easily just replace its HTML with the saved data on the next load of the page?

Thank you.

Comment: Are you able to create code snippet?

Comment: @TanDuong How do you mean?